# How do I use a Try and Exception to raise an error with a print message in Python?

Tags: python, exception, input, error-handling, try-catch

I'm trying to run a collatz in Python and I'm having trouble taking into account input that isn't an integer. I would like to have a Try and Except to work within my code that considers the user's non-integer input. Please see my code below.

```
number = int(input("Please enter a number: "))

def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(number // 2)
        return number // 2
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        print(number * 3 + 1)
        return number * 3 + 1

while number != 1:
    try:
        number = collatz(int(number))
    except ValueError:
        print("Something went wrong, please try again...")
```

Comment: I believe that `elif` in `collatz()` can be replaced with a simple `else`.

Comment: @AMC. Thanks for the suggestion. It didn't like it for some reason. It only takes the ' elif ' .

Comment: What do you mean by _didn’t like it_?

Comment: @AMC `elif` allows me to have another condition which is what I need my code to do. The `else` doesn't allow another condition.

Comment: My point is that in the code you shared above, it should be possible to replace the elif with an else. If `number % 2` is not 0, then it must be 1, there’s no need to check a second time, no?

Comment: @AMC I see, my mistake. Yup, that seems to be working just the same. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not using the try except when you are calling int on the input, which is why it is still erroring. You should use 2 while loops like this:

```
number = input("Please enter a number: ")
while not number.isdigit():
    number = input("Please enter a number again: ")
number = int(number)

def collatz(number):
    if number % 2 == 0:
        print(number // 2)
        return number // 2
    elif number % 2 == 1:
        print(number * 3 + 1)
        return number * 3 + 1
```

With try-except (in this case don't include the initial stuff in the other solution):

```
while True:
    try:
        number = int(input("Please enter a number: "))
        break
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: Thanks @whackamadoodle3000. This seemed to work while also taking care of user input of any integer <= 1. For whatever reason, I decided to use a Try-Catch, do you know what the correct way would be for me to write it out?